# MySql to .txt in C# WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, text, streamwriter, executereader

I am trying to get a table from my local database to download into a .txt. I've and I'm honestly at a loss.

It has to be in a txt for simplicity of other users. I've tried a few different ways, I've tried to call it as if I was writing it to a datagrid, which didn't work.

I am getting results from the Reader @

```
while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dbReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                }
```

So it is pulling and reading the information, it's just not writing it to a txt file. Here's the code.

```
 private void btnDLSql_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string dbConnection = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=12345";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select GUID,BanTime,Reason from bans.bans order by BanType asc", conDataBase);

            conDataBase.Open();

            MySqlCommand command = conDataBase.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader dbReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (dbReader != null)
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\mccla\Desktop\A3Bans.txt", true);

                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dbReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                }
            }

            conDataBase.Close();

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the questions, I usually try and figure stuff out on my own. But just can't find any information for this.

Comment: Have you tried putting `file.Write(dbReader.GetValue(0).ToString());` instead of the message box show? (Also, are you closing the file?)

Comment: If you want to write a file, try writing some code that actually puts things in the file.

Comment: `dbReader` can never be `null`.

Comment: You should use `using` statements.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks I've only been learning c# for 3 days... and I only know bits and pieces of code from simple stuff.. so this is a big project, any pointers are always appreciated.

Comment: Yup.. needed to close file... smh, i thought I had it too.. Not I just gotta figure out the formatting. Thanks Gents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently aren't writing to your file or closing it when you are done. You should also be using `using` statements, as mentioned by SLaks in the comments.

You could probably simplify your code to:

```
        var dbConnection = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=12345";
        using (var conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection))
        using (var selectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select GUID,BanTime,Reason from bans.bans order by BanType asc", conDataBase)) {
            var dbReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\mccla\Desktop\A3Bans.txt", true)) {
                while (dbReader.Read()) {
                    file.Write(dbReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will start looking at ways to simplify, as I said in the comments above, C# is the 1st language I'm really  getting into besides a few small project.